# How can i iterate foreach without IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How can i iterate foreach without IEnumerable

**Repo.cs**

```
public Employee GetEmployee(int id)
        {

            var x = (from n in db.Employee
                     where n.Emp_Id==id
                     select n);
            return x.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetEmpById(int id)
{
     var x = ObjRepo.GetEmployee(id);

    return View(x);
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

Here I'm gettin Error as **The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Mvc_Application.Models.Employee', but this dictionary requires a model item of type** 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Mvc_Application.Models.Employee]'.

```
@model IEnumerable<Mvc_Application.Models.Employee>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: You're mixing List and Singleton , in multiple places. Think about what you actually want first.

Comment: Your returning a single `Employee` to a view which expects a collection of `Employee`

Comment: You have a double `return`. The code as shown does not even use the View...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are passing single object to your view. and in view you are accepting `IEnumerable` of Employee

change in view

```
@model Mvc_Application.Models.Employee
@*  your code *@
```

Comment: plz review my code i just updated

Comment: @MDmohi : Please update code in view `.cshtml` file as I suggested. It will work

Comment: Error as Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Mvc_Application.Models.Employee' because 'Mvc_Application.Models.Employee' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Why you are using for loop. as it wil have only one email. so just use `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)` and remove your `foreach loop`

Comment: I have soo many columns Knowly i remove all othe colums

Comment: @MDmohi : Than you need to write similar to `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)` for each column.

Answer (score 0):

If this page is intended to show data from a single employee, then, it's model should be @model `Mvc_Application.Models.Employee`.

Comment: plz review my updated code

Comment: @MDmohi What do you want to show in your view, a list of employees, or a single employee?